# includes method not checking input against array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

First off, new to Javascript ... trying to write good code!
As a test for the app I am writing, I want to have a user's name input via prompt checked against an array that will enable user to keep going or prevent user from doing so.

I can get includes to filter properly when I assign a value to a variable:

```
var name, excluded_Persons;
var name = "jim"

function denyEntry () {

var excluded_Persons = ["bob", "jim"];

    if (excluded_Persons.includes(name)) {
    alert("You may not enter!!");
    enterName ();
    }

    else {
        allowEntry ();
    }
}
denyEntry ();

function allowEntry () {

    alert("You have been granted access!!");
}
```

returns "You may not enter!" 
However, when I include the function enabling the user to input a name,

```
    var name, excluded_Persons;

function enterName () {
    var name = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase();
    }

enterName ();

function denyEntry () {

    var excluded_Persons = ["bob", "jim"];

    if (excluded_Persons.includes(name)) {
    alert("You may not enter!!");
    enterName ();
    }

    else {
        allowEntry ();
    }

}

denyEntry ();
```

any name the user inputs (including "bob" and "jim") returns "You have been granted access!" The includes function is being bypassed.

Am I missing an argument in either the enterName function or the denyEntry function?

Comment: You should stop where you are and consider using a server side solution for this. Dealing with user access client side is way to easy to bypass.

Comment: Remove `var` in front of the variable `name` that's inside the enterName function.

Comment: @devlincarnate, thanks!

Comment: @LGSon, the app I'm working on doesn't actually involve authentication. If it did I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring the Name  inside function `enterName()` so its scope is limited to only that function. Make name global variable:

```js
var name, excluded_Persons;

function enterName () {
     name = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase();
}

enterName ();

function denyEntry () {

    var excluded_Persons = ["bob", "jim"];
    console.log(name);
    if (excluded_Persons.includes(name)) {
    alert("You may not enter!!");
    enterName ();
    }

    else {
        allowEntry ();
    }

}

denyEntry ();
```

Comment: The first line declares name as a global.  The problem is that there's a local variable of the same name inside the enterName function.

Comment: Closer.  You have `var name` declared twice.  Remove the second one.